# Import error com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.R

Tags: android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock

I have error in the project from https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock I can't import com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.R nor the R class is generated in "generate java files"

I need your help!

Comment: Are you using `eclipse` or `Android Studio` ?

Comment: Open your `Problems` view, all your errors will be listed there

Comment: I can't solve these problems. This is one 
Description Resource Path Location Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable DirectionsInputActivity.java /GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/src/com/ecs/google/maps/v2/fragment line 66 Java Problem (I can send a picture problems in your mail?)